I cant set env variable in my node scripts
when im trying to set my mongo url in node scripts its not working
C:\Users\we\Desktop\Proj1\project>npm run dev

> dev
> set "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017" && echo %MONGO_URL%

%MONGO_URL%

thats the srcipt im trying to run i want to set the env using the command

What do you mean by not working? What is the output of the command?

the output is:
%MONGO_URL%
but when i do the command manually im getting the connection string

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You'll need to use delayed expansion to set the variable and read it at the same time. Alternatively you can use 'call'.
"test-env": "set TEST_ENV=value&&call echo %TEST_ENV%"

npm run test-env

Output: value
Remove the whitespace between value and && otherwise it will add the space to the variable value.
